# Чем в objective c можно заменить cin>>a[i]?

Tags: objective-c

Чем в objective c можно заменить cin>>a[i]?

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C это надстройка над Си, поэтому все операции ввода/вывода из стандартной библиотеки последнего будут работать:

```
int x = 0;
scanf("%d", &x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать С++, для этого надо использовать файл с расширением `*.mm_` вместо `*.m`, таким образом сообщив компилятору что вы используете синтаксические конструкции С++ (более детальную информацию можно найти в нете, к примеру, в справке apple, которую я считаю одной из самых информативных).

Если же вы хотите использовать чистый С тогда используйте функции сишных либ, аля `stdio.h`

`run.mm:` (C++)

```
#include <iostream>
int main() { 
    int a;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << a + 1;
}
```

`run.m:` (C)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { 
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("%d", a+1);
}
```